# How to select all text displayed in browser and copy and paste it in the Notepad?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I would like to select all of the text displayed on the page and paste it into the Notepad. I have the following code but it is not working.

```
Browser("Display Token").Page("Display Token").WebEdit("html tag:=TEXTAREA").Click
Browser("Display Token").Page("Display Token").WebEdit("html tag:=TEXTAREA").Type  micCtrlDwn + "a" + micCtrlUp
Browser("Display Token").Page("Display Token").WebEdit("html tag:=TEXTAREA").Type  micCtrlDwn + "c" + micCtrlUp
```

The first line with a `Click` did work, but for the 2nd line I'm getting the following error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method: Browser (..).Page(...).WebEdit(...).Type'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to copy and paste the text?

To get the text of the webpage using QTP/UFT

```
sPageText = Browser("Display Token").Page("Display Token").object.innerText
```

To write to a txt file,

```
Set oFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
oFileName="c:\<filepath>\pagecontent.txt"
Set oFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile(oFileName,True)
oFile.Write sPageText 
oFile.Close
```

Comment: How to copy all but strip out "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>"?

Comment: If only this, I would just replace (assume sPageText has the text)

sPageText = Replace(sPageText,"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?>", "")